# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getAverageScore'

Tags: python

```
  import re
class HashTable:
    def __init__(self, keyword, averageScore = 0, occurences = 0):
        self.size = 20011
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.averageScore = averageScore
        self.occurences = occurences
        self.slots = [None] * self.size 
        self.data = [None] * self.size

    def getAverageScore(self) :
        return self.averageScore

    def getWord(self) :
        return self.keyword

    def getOccurences(self) :
        return self.occurences

    def addNewScore(self, newScore) :
        oldScoreSum = self.averageScore * self.occurences
        self.occurences = self.occurences + 1
        self.averageScore = (oldScoreSum + newScore) / (self.occurences)


    def put(self, key, data): 
        hash_value = self.hash_function(key,len(self.slots)) 

        if self.slots[hash_value] == None:
            self.slots[hash_value] = key
            self.data[hash_value] = data
        else: 
            if self.slots[hash_value] == key:
               self.data[hash_value] = data #replace 
            else:
                next_slot = self.rehash(hash_value, len(self.slots))
                while self.slots[next_slot] != None and \
                            self.slots[next_slot] != key:
                 next_slot = self.rehash(next_slot, len(self.slots)) 

                if self.slots[next_slot] == None:
                    self.slots[next_slot] = key
                    self.data[next_slot] = data
                else:
                    self.data[next_slot] = data #replace
    def hash_function(self, key, size):
        return key % size

    def rehash(self, old_hash, size):
        return (old_hash + 1) % size


    def get(self, key): 
        start_slot = self.hash_function(key, len(self.slots))

        data = None
        stop = False
        found = False
        position = start_slot

        while self.slots[position] != None and not found and not stop:
            if self.slots[position] == key:
                found = True
                data = self.data[position]
        else:
            position=self.rehash(position, len(self.slots))
            if position == start_slot:
                stop = True
        return data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, data):
        self.put(key, data)

    def printWordStatistic(self) :
           print("Word          : ", self.keyword)
           print("Occurences    : ", self.occurences)
           print("Average Score : ", self.occurences, "\n\n")

    def printAllWordStatistic(wordDictionary) :
        for wordStatistic in table.getWord :
            wordStatistic.printWordStatistic()
# To rate a review based on the training data


fileInstance = open("movieReviews.txt",'r')
fileText = fileInstance.read()
table = HashTable(fileText)
# Assuming, that each review is seperated by following delimeter
reviewSplits = fileText.splitlines()
for review in reviewSplits :
    #succesfully splits review into lines
    #print(review)
    review = review.strip()
    if review == "" :
        continue
        # In each review, first line contains the score and the
        # subsequent lines contains the text
        score = float(review[0])
        print(score)
        for i in range(1, len(review)) :
            # Splitting out the words in each line of the review
            wordSplits = re.split("\t| ", review[i])
        for word in wordSplits :
            if word == "" :
                continue
                # If it is already present, then update the score and count
                # Otherwise just add the new entry to the dictionary
            if table.keyword(word) :
                wordStatistic = table.getWord(word)
                wordStatistic.addNewScore(score)
            else :
                wordStatistic = HashTable(word, score, 1)
                table[word] = wordStatistic
# Training Phase Completed

# To print the statistics of all words in the dictionary 
def calculateAverageOfReview(review) :
    review.replace("\t", " ")
    review.replace("\n", " ")
    wordSplits = review.split(" ")
    averageScore = 0.0
    totalCount = 0;
    for word in wordSplits :
        if table.getWord():
            averageScore += table.getWord().getAverageScore().split(" ")
            totalCount = totalCount + 1
        if totalCount != 0 :
            return averageScore / totalCount
        return -1

while (True) :
    print("\nEnter a review, (enter empty-line to save) : ")
    multiLines = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line:
            multiLines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    inputReview = '\n'.join(multiLines)
    averageScore = calculateAverageOfReview(inputReview)
    if averageScore != -1 :
        if averageScore >= 2.50 :
            print("Positive Review")
        else :
            print("Negative Review")
    else :
        print("Unable to rate the review")
    if input("\nDo you want to continue ? (Y/N) : ") != "Y" :
        print("Quitting the session. Good Bye !")
        exit()
```

I am writing a code for a movie review sentimental analysis. I have the following inputs and outputs below

1-  Enter a review -- Press return to exit:

A weak script that ends with a quick and boring finale

The review has an average value of 1.79128

Negative Sentiment

2-  Enter a review -- Press return to exit:

Loved every minute of it

The review has an average value of 2.39219

Positive Sentiment

So when I run the code I get an Attribute error like this

averageScore += table.getWord().getAverageScore().split(" ")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getAverageScore'

What could be the issue?

Comment: The problem is that, `table.getWord()` returns string itself and `str` (`self.keyword) object has no attribute `getAverageScore()`. So, you should call `table.getAverageScore()` independently

Comment: at which line can I call it

Comment: Your getWord() method returns a string, not a HashTable object. getAverageScore() is a method for HadhTable objects, you are trying to call the method on the returned `keyword` string.

Comment: Change `averageScore += table.getWord().getAverageScore().split(" ")` to `averageScore += table.getAverageScore()`